# Cannot add subproject to gradle buildscript classpath in 7.3

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a subprojectA and subprojectB. There are some artifacts from subprojectA that i need to build subprojectB. It seems that after upgrading to 7.3, i can no longer configure it like this.
Getting the error 'Cannot transition to state Configure as already transitioning to this state.'
May I know if there is an alternative or a solution to the error?

subprojectb build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath project(':subprojectA')
    }
}

plugins {
  ...
}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make subprojectA an included build instead of a subproject, then use the GAV coordinates instead of the project dir.

```
//build.gradle
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example:subprojectA:1.0'
    }
}

plugins {
  ...
}

...

// settings.gradle
includeBuild('./subprojectA')
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/structuring_software_products.html#connecting_components

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you did? I have the same issue, it was working prior to Gradle 7.3. In my case I have all of my projects included in the `settings.gradle` at the top level.

Comment: Have edited my answer.